Substituting for 1N34A diode to change range of microwave detector
In connection to an earlier question, this DIY device for detecting "mini radio" EMF seemed like it might work to detect microwaves generally, assuming diodes exist to replace the 1N34A rectifiers in the circuit, when looking for higher frequencies.
So my question is very specific: what diode might work in this circuit if instead of 300 MHz we wish to detect 24 GHz (not 2.4 GHz)?

The folks who built this energy harvester mention using MACOM MA4E2054A Schottky diodes to rectify 24GHz RF to power small devices.  You could use them in your microwave detector in place of the 1N34A diodes.
The MA4E2054A Schottky diodes are SMD parts - this is good.  At the frequencies you want to look at, inductance of the leads and the PCB traces will play a part as well as the capacitance between conductors.  The length and the shape of the PCB traces will influence how well your circuit works.  Even the PCB material is a problem - variations in the makeup of standard FR4 PCB material and epoxy will influence your circuit.
You will need to build your circuit as small as possible, using the physically smallest components you can get.

I built something similar for 2.4GHz a few years ago.  I used 0201 sized capacitors and some BAT63 Schottky diodes.
Schematic:

Circuit board back:

Circuit board front:

You could do something similar, with antennas on the front and the LEDs on the back.  Make multiples of a simplified circuit (single diode, capacitor, and LED for each antenna) and lay them out in a grid on a large PCB, then wave the radar gun across it.  The difficulty is that it won't be very sensitive - you may not be able to detect the radar gun from any distance.  I expect the range to be centimeters, decimeters if you are lucky.  The one I built was just for fun - it has a range of a few centimeters for WiFi and less than 1 meter for 160MHz.

This is a really helpful and direct response. Thanks.
